# Why do cmd, runas and psexec open different associated applications?

Tags: c#, cmd, psexec, runas, associated-types

I need to open documents/files with their associated application and **a specific user** in C#.

Problem 1: Process.Start() with Domain/Username/Password (in ProcessStartInfo) doesn't accept an (e. g.) image file anymore, it expects an executable then (e. g. cmd.exe).

Problem 2: Process.Start() with Username "doesn't find the directory" when I try to call cmd.exe.

Problem 3: When using "runas" I cannot supply the specific user's password.

Problem 4: When using "psexec" (which takes a password) Windows 10 asks me for the application to open the image with. (But it works fine with e.g. an Excel file.)

Why is "cmd" just opening the image fine with the Windows image viewer while "runas" opens the image with Paint.net and "psexec" asks for the application???

```
var cmdParamsA = @"c:\temp\Image.png";
Process.Start("cmd", cmdParamsA);

var cmdParamsB = @"/noprofile /user:domain\user cmd /k start c:\temp\Image.png";
Process.Start("runas", cmdParamsB);

var cmdParamsC = @"-u domain\user -p password cmd /k start c:\temp\Image.png";
Process.Start(@"c:\temp\PsExec.exe", cmdParamsC);
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share your [mcve] showing the different techniques.

Comment: It sounds like you have syntax errors in the calls to `runas` and `psexec`. Unless you post actual examples, it's impossible to help

Comment: Sure, I added the calls.

Comment: You don't need *any* of these programs to execute an  application. All of them do the same thing `Process.Start` does with different parameters. Explain what you actually want to do

Comment: If you want to start a program run `Process.Start(pathToExe)`, not `Process.Start("cmd",pathToExe)`. If you want to impersonate another user, search for `Process.Start impersonation`. You'll find a lot of answers

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I cannot use the first approach with a specific user as it needs an executable supplied. (And I didn't want to get the application for each file type from the registry!) That's why I started to try cmd, runas, psexec.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I am not using "pathToExe" but "pathToFile" (e. g. the png).

Comment: @IngoB explain what you want to do and the actual problem, not what you thought would be the answer. If there *is* an associated program, `Process.Start` will work. `Process.Start(@"C:\Pictures\beedo1.gif")` works

Comment: @IngoB read the documentation for the method and the class. You can open images using the associated programs just fine.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Right, but it doesn't work anymore as soon as you set Domain/Username/Password in ProcessStartInfo! You need to supply an executable then, not the (e. g.) image. You get an "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform" error then.

Comment: @IngoB google it. There are duplicate questions already. If you have issues with impersonation *and* after you've tried the duplicates, post a new question explaining what the problem is.

Comment: Be sure you aren't asking for something impossible though. You can start an application as another user. You can't see *that user's desktop from your own* though. What you ask is how to have the *shell* find the program. If you can't access the shell because you aren't logged in interactively, that's it.